# Web View not working with some specific url

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, pinterest, webviewclient

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "https://www.pinterest.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl(url);       
    }
}
```

Web View is not loading "https://www.pinterest.com"  within the application but it was working with chrome browser using intent. I tried of other urls it's working. While loading "https://www.pinterest.com" using webview, getting the output screen like below
[image]

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: @ArunRavichandran your code is woking fine in my device just change the url like this `String url = "https://www.pinterest.com/";`

Answer (score 9):

You try this:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://www.pinterest.com/");
```

In manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: Thanks. Its Working

Comment: Why do we need to provide storage access to Pinterest?

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks. I had issue with loading Iheart and after Dom storage enable it works

Answer (score 1):

set the JavascriptEnabled and AllowContentAccess and setDomStorageEnabled to true in settings