# Open url in webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I make the webview and put it activity.

And set webview,

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Set WebView client
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
// Load the webpage
browser.loadUrl(url);
```

I understand that, is there any url in webview, webview detect the url and enable to move that url.

But it had no action.

I want when I load the url in webview, if webview has url text, auto detect it and when I touch that text, enable to move that url.

---

update

```
<p style="float: left; width: 116px; text-align: left;"><font color="orange">Homepage</font></p><p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 120px;"><font><?=$Homepage?></font></p>
```

Comment: You clicked some link in website and it wasn't move?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Url in webView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269059/open-url-in-webview-in-android)

Comment: @MeosCoder Yes, it's correct. I update my answer

Comment: You can add this functionality directly into html script. Use <a> tag for display text and webview can handle it.

Comment: Try setting webview like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49625441/4904995

Comment: @SardarKhan Yes so I put the a href tag in website, but how I can get it?

Comment: @Leo No, it's not answer that I want

Comment: @PolarisNation why you want to get the Tag.?

Comment: @SardarKhan Ok Thanks, I followed your advice

Answer (score 0):

According to Android documentation (and also to my experience), true return value for **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** means "don't load this url".

You should not override **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** unless you want to apply url filtering

view.LoadUrl calls is not needed here, since **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** is called on each url loading

Android doc : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)